# ¿Cómo obtener el valor total acumulado de un mes en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente duda con SQL: quiero sacar el mes máximo de compra de cierto artículo.

Con esta consulta listo la compra del artículo acumulada en LOS ULTIMOS 12 MESES:

```
SELECT ARTICULO.ARTICULO, ARTICULO.DESCRIPCION,
       sum(LINEA.cantidad * LINEA.multiplicador_ev) AS MexMAX
FROM factura_linea LINEA (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN LICASA.factura FACTURA (NOLOCK) ON LINEA.factura = FACTURA.factura
     INNER JOIN licasa.ARTICULO ON LINEA.articulo = ARTICULO.articulo
WHERE FACTURA.FECHA BETWEEN FORMAT((Dateadd(month,-12,GETDATE())),'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000')
                        AND FORMAT(EOMONTH(Dateadd(month,-1,GETDATE())),'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59.999')
  AND LINEA.ANULADA='N' and ARTICULO.ARTICULO ='TR900'
GROUP BY ARTICULO.ARTICULO, ARTICULO.DESCRIPCION, month(factura.FECHA)
```

**Este es el resultado:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es otra consulta, o si se puede hacer de otra forma, que me tome estos valores y me saque la máxima compra acumulada en los últimos 12 meses.

Gracias de antemano!
Saludos

Comment: Creo que, ya que es dado un articulo, agregarle `top 1` y `order by sum(LINEA.cantidad * LINEA.multiplicador_ev)` es la opcion mas sensilla

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la funcion **Max()** para obtener el valor mas alto de una columna:

```sql
    SELECT MAX(MexMAX) AS masVecesVendido 
    FROM (SELECT ARTICULO.ARTICULO, ARTICULO.DESCRIPCION,
           sum(LINEA.cantidad * LINEA.multiplicador_ev) AS MexMAX
    FROM factura_linea LINEA (NOLOCK)
         INNER JOIN LICASA.factura FACTURA (NOLOCK) ON LINEA.factura = FACTURA.factura
         INNER JOIN licasa.ARTICULO ON LINEA.articulo = ARTICULO.articulo
    WHERE FACTURA.FECHA BETWEEN FORMAT((Dateadd(month,-12,GETDATE())),'yyyy-MM-01 00:00:00.000')
                            AND FORMAT(EOMONTH(Dateadd(month,-1,GETDATE())),'yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59.999')
      AND LINEA.ANULADA='N' and ARTICULO.ARTICULO ='TR900'
    GROUP BY ARTICULO.ARTICULO, ARTICULO.DESCRIPCION, month(factura.FECHA)) resMeses
```

Comment: Sería bueno, que mencionaras algo acerca el concepto de subconsulta que es la solución que en definitiva esta proponiendo. Saludos.